# Cartesian product between two tables when the second one doesn't have all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cartesian-product, sql-server-2019

I have 2 tables in SQL Server and I would like to get all possible combinations by their IDs even when the second one has no records, I would like to know if there is a better solution than mine.

My 2 tables are:

- Companies (CompanyId, Tot1, Tot2) with 10 records
- Motors (MotorId, CompanyId_FK, TotSales1, TotSales2) with 4 records

, here the script to create and populate them:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [CompanyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tot1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Tot2] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Motors]    Script Date: 10/15/2021 9:18:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Motors](
    [MotorId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotSales1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotSales2] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Motors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MotorId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (1, 300, 200)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (2, 400, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (3, 500, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (4, 600, 200)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (5, 700, 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (6, 800, 400)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (7, 900, 300)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (8, 50, 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (9, 80, 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId], [Tot1], [Tot2]) VALUES (10, 40, 10)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Companies] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([MotorId], [CompanyId], [TotSales1], [TotSales2]) VALUES (1, 4, 35, 23)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([MotorId], [CompanyId], [TotSales1], [TotSales2]) VALUES (2, 5, 140, 70)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([MotorId], [CompanyId], [TotSales1], [TotSales2]) VALUES (3, 7, 200, 24)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([MotorId], [CompanyId], [TotSales1], [TotSales2]) VALUES (4, 9, 2, 1)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Motors] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Motors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Motors_Companies] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Motors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Motors_Companies]
GO
```

I need as result set a list of all possible combination containing a Motor and a Company even when there is no sales:

| CompanyId | MotorId | Tot1 | Tot2 | TotSales1 | TotSales2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 600 | 200 | 35 | 23 |
| 4 | 2 | 600 | 200 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 3 | 600 | 200 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 4 | 600 | 200 | NULL | NULL |

I created a CTE by CROSS JOIN with only CompanyId and MotorId and then I joined the other 2 in this way:

```
;WITH myTable AS (
SELECT Companies.CompanyId, MotorId
FROM Companies CROSS JOIN Motors
GROUP BY Companies.CompanyId, MotorId)
 
SELECT myTable.*, Tot1, Tot2, TotSales1,TotSales2 FROM myTable
INNER JOIN Companies ON myTable.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Motors ON myTable.CompanyId = Motors.CompanyId AND myTable.MotorId = Motors.MotorId
```

Is there a better solution? To avoid misunderstanding: I can't change the sequence of the fields to map the results with a C# class.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Ideally you should have a completely separate `Motor` table, and this `Motors` table should really be called `CompanyMotor`, then you simply cross-join the first two, and left join this last.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky is my post correct now?

Comment: @Charlieface yes, like I did with the CTE, right?

Comment: Ideally it should a real physical table. Your current design is somewhat flawed

Comment: @Charlieface I agree with you if I would store data or if I have to create a permanent table but I need only a temporary solution to get the result: it's a oneshot query. But thanks for your comment, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close to the answer... just do not do the `GROUP BY` in your CTE and you will get the result that you want:

```sql
;WITH myTable AS (
SELECT Companies.CompanyId, MotorId
FROM Companies CROSS JOIN Motors
) 
SELECT myTable.*, Tot1, Tot2, TotSales1,TotSales2 FROM myTable
INNER JOIN Companies ON myTable.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Motors ON myTable.CompanyId = Motors.CompanyId AND myTable.MotorId = Motors.MotorId
```

I am not sure why you thought you needed the `GROUP BY`, but since you wanted all possible combinations there is no need for it.